# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ix}\cos(nx)dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

I now that I can prove this by the definition of $\epsilon$ $\delta$, but I was playing and I found that if I use the substitution

$\cos(nx) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{inx} + e^{-inx})$

Hence, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}\sin([n+1]x) + \frac{1}{n-1}\sin([n-1]x)\biggr|_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0$$

It's something wrong with my solution?

Comment: To me, this is very correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing integration by parts

$$A_n=||\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ix}\cos(nx)dx||=||\frac{e^{ix}(n\sin{nx}+i \cos{nx})}{n^2-1}]_{-\pi}^{\pi}||_2=|-\frac{2n \sin{n\pi}}{n^2-1}|=0$$

where $||.||_2$ denotes the complex absolute value.

Thus $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n=0$

Comment: Your own solution is mistaken (namely, the regions where $\cos(nx)$ is positive and negative change when $n$ increases). $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert \cos(nx)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x = 4$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MichaelLee i edited my answer.you were right..thanks for point it out

Comment: You have another slight mistake now, but it doesn't affect the correctness of your solution. $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ix}\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{e^{ix}(n\sin(nx)+i\cos(nx))}{n^2-1}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = -\frac{2n\sin(n\pi)}{n^2-1}$$ You switched the $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: The question is "It's something wrong with my solution?" How is this answer (irrespectively of its mathematical inaccuracies) addressing it? One of the upvoters or the OP themselves might want to explain.

Comment: @MichaelLee just checked in wolfram and it gives the smae result as mine..i edited according to your comment for now but are you sure?

Comment: @Did i just wanted to do the calculations for the O.P..if the O.P is ok i can deleted eventully..its not a problem for me

Comment: Why not address directly the question "(Is) something wrong with **MY** solution?" instead, or, in addition?

Comment: @Did any other approaches are good for me. and I'm wondering if you are the one downvoting my questions and WHY?

Comment: @RichardClare So it appears you had in mind to ask a question whose scope is larger than the declared one. Why not. Only, next time, perhaps try to be more explicit/exact about what it is that you are really asking. // Your query about votes is odd since disclosing the details of one's votes is frankly outside of the way the site was designed (if you pause two minutes to think about it, this should be clear). Do you also enquire about upvotes on your posts?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, I'm sure. http://i.imgur.com/PeK78J8.png

Comment: Also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(ix)cos(nx)+from+x+%3D+-pi+to+x+%3D+pi